# JEST: how do I write a unit test for the functions in Promise?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, promise, jestjs

I have a React store, the code structure is simple as this:

```
    get: function() {
       var getA = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
           RestApi.post(url, data, re => resolve(re), re=>reject(re)); // this makes an ajax calls to the rest api
       } );
       var getB = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
           RestApi.post(url, data, re => resolve(re), re=>reject(re));
       } );
       var getC = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
           RestApi.post(url, data, re => resolve(re), re=>reject(re)); 
       } );

       Promise.all( getA, getB, getC ).then( values => {
           this.set(values);
      } ); 
   },
   set: function(value){
      // code to set the store.
   }
```

so I'm trying to add unit test for this code using JEST, but I'm totally lost on how the JEST/Jasmine works with promise, and how do I test the ajax within the promise is called?

Comment: Your promises are never resolved and your `all` call is wrong. Is this really what you are doing?